# Saving utf8 data to latin-swedish_ci MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

It seems that this question gets asked a lot, but I didn't find an answer that fits my setup and doen't ask me to convert my database.

### Setup

I work in PHP, my db is latin_swedish_ci and the charset in the  is utf-8.

I found a way to convert the db text to utf-8 using an homemade function that uses a mix of **stripslashes()** and **utf8_encode()**. I call it **fxUnescape()**.

I also uses **fxEscape()** for MySQL purposes. It uses **addslashes()** and **utf8_decode()**.

### Problem

So here is my problem. When data is sent by a form, using **fxEscape()** breaks the accents and save them as **?** in the database.

What do I do wrong?

p.s. To make things worse, Ihave a mix of iso-8859-1 and utf-8 encoded php files.

### my posted data

```
Array
(
    [com_titre_billing] => m
    [com_prenom_billing] => Jean-SÃ©bastien
    [com_nom_billing] => Proulx
    [pay_iso_billing] => CA
    [com_infolettre] => 1
    [btn_enregistrer] => Enregistrer
)
```

**NEVERMIND: found the problem, there was an extra utf8_encode in the code**

Comment: You want to be UTF8 all the way not ISO or latin1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: What kind of language format does the document use? ANSI or UTF-8? Set your document to be UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: "my db is latin_swedish_ci and the charset in the is utf-8" -- that's a contradiction.

Comment: utf8_encode -- never needed.

Comment: stripslashes -- never needed

Comment: ok I added mysqlio charset to utf and the display is ok. But any form post is not utf8.The queries are handled in a string. Is that an issue?

Comment: my posted date looks like this:
Array
(
    [com_titre_billing] => m
    [com_prenom_billing] => Jean-SÃ©bastien
    [com_nom_billing] => Proulx
    [pay_iso_billing] => CA
    [com_infolettre] => 1
    [btn_enregistrer] => Enregistrer
)